# The total space of the standard quaternionic Hopf fibration of an $S^3$ fiber bundle over $S^4.$

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

I am trying to understand the paper "Milnor's Construction of Exotic 7-Spheres" by Rachel McEnroe ([link](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2015/REUPapers/McEnroe.pdf)). Here's the abstract:

> [image]

I do not understand why the total space of this fiber bundle is given by:

> [image]

Could anyone explain this also to me please?

Comment: This is the second time you've tagged a question about this algebraic topology paper with algebraic-geometry. Please pay attention to this in the future.

Comment: @KReiser thanks for clarifying, I will be careful next time.

Comment: What is your definition of "standard quaternionic Hopf fibration"?  From perusing the article, it seems the author *defines* "standard quaternionic Hopf fibration" to have that total space.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I did not understand this from the paper, could you please clarify where was this mentioned by the author?

Comment: Well I just can't find "Standard quaternionic Hopf fibration" anywhere else in the article.  Also, the definition used is... odd.  For example, I would interpret the notation $z,w\neq 0$ to mean that *both* $z$ and $w$ are non-zero.  But from the context, it seems as though one can be $0$ as long as the other isn't.

Comment: It also seems as though the equality should be  $wx = zy$ instead of $xw = zy$, and that $(x,y)$ should be restricts to the unit sphere $S^7\subseteq \mathbb{H}^2$.  I could, however, be misreading - I've never heard the phrase "..Hopf fibration of an $S^3$-bundle over $S^4$."  I think of the Hopf fibration as a map $S^7\rightarrow S^4$, not something which applies to every $S^3$-bundle over $S^4$.  But if I'm not  misreading, perhaps reading from an alternate source would be better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading the lines that follow where the pre images of $U_1$ and $U_2$ are computed, I believe that there's a slight inaccuracy in the definition of the total space.

In section 2, McEnroe defines the Quaternionic Hopf Fibration as the map $\pi \colon \mathbb{S}^7 \subset \mathbb{H}^2 \to \mathbb{S}^4 = \mathbb{HP}^1$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto [x;y]$ and the total space is $\mathbb{S}^7$.

Now in section 3, it seems that instead of getting $\mathbb{S}^7$ itself as the total space, they consider the graph of $\pi$, that is,
$$ \{ ((x,y),\pi(x,y)) \ : \ (x,y) \neq (0,0) \} = \{ ((x,y),[z;w]) \ : \ x = \lambda z, y = \lambda w \ \text{for some} \ \lambda \in \mathbb{H} \} \subset \mathbb{H}^2 \times \mathbb{HP}^1 $$
which is also the total space, since a given space is homeomorphic to the graph of any map coming from it (here $\pi$ is actually considered as having $\mathbb{H}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ as its domain, but it's unimportant for now). Notice that in this representation, $\pi$ is simply the projection on the second coordinate $\mathbb{HP}^1$.

This characterization of the total space makes sense when considering the lines that follow in the article and if we were to try to naively simplify the expression defining this set, we could get something like
$$ \frac{x}{z} = \lambda = \frac{y}{w} \iff xw = zy$$
which (at least in the way I've done it) is incorrect since multiplication isn't commutative and we were assuming both $z,w$ nonzero.